# Sound Intensity Level

Tags: physics

The question is:

The noise from a vacuum cleaner is 85 dB while that from a television set is 78 dB. What is the intensity level of the two sounds together?

i can't find the right formula.

thanks.

Comment: You convert both to power (in Watt, horsepower, pirate-ninjas, or whatever your favourite denomination is), you add them together, and then you convert back into dB.

Comment: i still cant answer.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is 
$$10\log(10^{[\text{dB of sound 1}]/10} + 10^{\text{[dB of sound2]}/10})$$ where Log(x) is the base-10 logarithm.
Plugging in your numbers we get
$85.790097$ dB

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

dBs are logarithmic and so can't be manipulated directly.

Express them on a linear scale, do the addition and then covert back to dB.